# ¿Cómo se puede hacer más eficiente este REPLACE?

Tags: sql-server

¿Cómo se puede mejorar este REPLACE?
La idea es eliminar todas esas palabras, cambiarlas por nada '' (vacío)

```
CAST(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.tmp_ColocacionFiduandina.cfa_DESCR, '1800CC', ''), '^', ''),'FL!',''),' MT ',''),'1500CC',''),'800CC',''),'3000CC',''),'1000CC',''),'1600CC',''),'PASAJ.',''),'1200CC',''),'2000CC',''),'2300CC',''),'GT',''),'1400CC',''),'1!',''),'2!.',''),'3!',''),'4!',''),'5!',''),'6!',''),'7!',''),'2500CC',''),'PICK UP',''),'1300CC',''),'1600',''),'1300',''),'1800C',''),' AT ',''),' MT',''),'1.2',''),'^2!',''),'1.4',''),'2700CC','2000C'),'COUPE',''),'1.6',''),'SENCILLA',''),'LIMITED',''),'1500C%',''),'2400CC',''),'2400C',''),'',''),'',''),'1100C%','')) AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS DESCRIPCION_ABR,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sabría decirte si mas eficiente, pero definitivamente mas mantenible así :

```
Declare @Reemplazos TABLE (
patron      NVARCHAR(100),
reemplazo   NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('1800CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('^','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('FL!','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('MT ','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('1500CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('800CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('3000CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('1000CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('1600CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('Pasaj.','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('1200CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('2000CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('2300CC','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('GT','');
INSERT INTO @Reemplazos VALUES ('1400CC','');
/* Aqui adicionas todos los string que quieras cambiar */

DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @test = 'Moto Yamaha 1800CC GT 2 Pasaj.';

SELECT @test = REPLACE(@test,patron,reemplazo) FROM @Reemplazos;

PRINT @test;
```

Comment: Según yo lo probé, funciona de acuerdo al requerimiento, el ejemplo está completo, solo hay que pegarlo en el Management Studio y probarlo.

Comment: Confundí el objetivo del ejercicio, en efecto, tienes razón, logra justamente lo que el OP requeire +1

Comment: Funciona a la perfección y desde luego que es mucho más mantenible ya que los valores son muchos y falta agregar más. Muchas gracias @Mauricio Atanache